# custom aspx page with default.master page CSS issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, custom, aspx

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ItemDetails.aspx.cs"  Inherits="namespacename" Debug="true" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/default.master" %>

<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages, 
 Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Issue I am facing is Css is not getting applied to the page.

although checked in page view source there css is attached .

```
</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/search.css?rev=Uoc0fsLIo87aYwT%2FGX5UPw%3D%3D">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?  rev=iIikGkMuXBs8CWzKDAyjsQ%3D%3D">
```

I am having blank site and this page is deployed to layout folder of SharePoint 2010.
How to resolve the css issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just resolved it,

by changing default.master to v4.master.. it works !!

```
 <%Page.... MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/v4.master" %>
```

from this url got to know ShrePoint 2010 uses v4.master as default master page:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-a-master-page-to-brand-your-site-HA102449505.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to note; Even though `link` is a [void element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#void-elements) the doctype used in SharePoint does not support it. So please consider closing your tags. Another thing is the space in the beginning of your querystring on corev4.css.
Both these should not directly cause your problem, but it's worth looking into.

Now, for checking if stylesheets are properly applied I usually follow this approach:

1. Fire up Chrome.
   (Yes it's not supported by SharePoint, but the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools)  are just too good).
2. Check **Resources** tab, if your stylesheet is properly included it will show up here under your correct frame and **Stylesheets**, if it is not listed then something is wrong.
3. In that case, check **Network** tab to check:

   1. Is the file even listed?
   2. Is the [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) correct?
   3. Is the [**Content-Type**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) in *Response Headers* set to **text/css**?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, just solved it. added a solution to.